# Is it safe to put a gas furnace in the same room as an electric clothes dryer?

Tags: furnace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an electric dryer be next to the gas furnace?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11151/can-an-electric-dryer-be-next-to-the-gas-furnace)

We are currently remodeling our house. Is it safe to put a gas furnace in the same room with an electric clothes dryer? The room has a vent and the dryer vent is to outside.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, yes, definitely. Absolutely no reason not to.

Comment: Just don't put it up against the furnace.  I think there is a code clearance you have to respect but if I remember right it's only 2 or 3 feet.